# MS Access, Query that selects * from db from 6AM to 6AM next day

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2010

I'm doing tons of approach to get this to work.
I need to generate reports based on table `dbAwarieZamkniete`.

I need to grab `ALL` from `dbAwarieZamkniete`, so when i select the `short date` from the text box in access form, based on that i want to run `query` that will grab data.

Let's say i need the records from 10.05.2016, that means i need records from 10.05.2016 06:00 till 11.05.2016 06:00.

My approaches were different, I was tried `union` for example, i won't paste all of them here, its just an example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
WHERE  Format(AwaZam.dataZgloszenia, "d-m-yyyy") = '03.09.2015'
AND ( Format(AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia, 'hh:mm') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '23:59' )

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
WHERE  Format(AwaZam.dataZgloszenia, "d-m-yyyy") = '04.09.2015'
AND (( Format(AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia, 'hh:mm') BETWEEN '00:00' AND '06:00' );
```

dataZgloszenia contains the date (as a d.m.yyyy) - short date

godzinaZgloszenia contains the time (as h:m) - short time

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to have just a datetime field for both date and time?

Comment: If there is an failure of some machine, people are making an accident form for the maintenance department (sms is sent as well using ms access to the workers cellphone). After they finish the fix they manualy edit times (for the collection of how much time was used to fix machine and later on for reports how long such machine wasnt working from 6am to 6am). Thats why i kept the time separated.

Comment: Is the Union not working as you expected?

Comment: This union somehow gets me results from different days, not only the range i want. Instead of like 10 records im getting like 600 from the large time frame (even from different months).

Comment: Or if ill try to get the days gap as `>=` `<=` instead of `=` and redo a bit the whole query, It also doesnt give me expected results.

Comment: `union somehow gets me results from different days`. Can you show example where any record was out of range?

Comment: In any case, I think it's more appropriate to do `WHERE AwaZam.dataZgloszenia = CONVERT(date, '03.09.2015')`

Comment: @Ustav that was with the different Union, i don't have it saved. This one in this post doesnt actually give me any of the results.

Comment: I think issue is with your date format. You mentioned `d.m.yyyy` but in code you are using `d-m-yyyy`. Correct it and try again. I gave an answer below too after getting rid of union.

Comment: Let us know the format of the table's fields. Are the dates and times saved as text? Or date/datetime/time?

Comment: @Andrea 1st pic - [imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/8Mg4kd0.png), 2nd pic - [imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/gWInerH.png)

Comment: date is as short date, time is as short time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always handle dates as dates, not text, no exceptions.

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
WHERE  AwaZam.dataZgloszenia + AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia
       Between 
           DateAdd("h", 6, #2016/05/10 00:00:00#)
           And
           DateAdd("h", 6 + 24, #2016/05/10 23:59:59#)
```

Using a date from a textbox:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
WHERE  AwaZam.dataZgloszenia + AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia
       Between 
           DateAdd("h", 6, DateValue([Forms]![YourForm]![YourTextbox]))
           And
           DateAdd("h", 6 + 24, DateValue([Forms]![YourForm]![YourTextbox]) + #23:59:59#)
```

Comment: This also gives me blank result. I really don't understand where is the issue.

Comment: Well, then you don't have date/times of 2016-05-10. Try another date.

Comment: dataZgloszenia exist for the day 03.05.2015 for example, i edited the query ofc [imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/8Mg4kd0.png), theres a structure of it: [imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/gWInerH.png)

Comment: dates are formatted as short date, times are formatted as short time

Comment: Oh ok, i got it to work, removed the seconds at the DateAdd, didnt seen that one. Thank You man, somehow i was sure that only Union approach will solve my problem.

Comment: The format has no importance; it is for display only.

Comment: Hmm, i started to see results after i removed the :00 of the seconds marker. Thats weird then.

Comment: Yes. `#2016/05/10 00:00:00#` and #2016/05/10 00:00#` represent identical values.

Comment: Question was answered, but may i have one more thing to ask? What if i want to put in the datefield of this query date value from text box (formated as date)?

Comment: I mean, i would like to insert "2016/05/10" from the form and leave the time mark in the query. Is that possible?

Comment: Thank You @Gustav , Your solution is a perfect fit for my needs. You were big help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are putting date as `d.m.yyyy` but in code you are using
   `d-m-yyyy`.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
   WHERE  Format(AwaZam.dataZgloszenia, "d.m.yyyy") = '03.09.2015'
   AND ( Format(AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia, 'hh:mm') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '23:59' )

   UNION ALL

   SELECT *
   FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
   WHERE  Format(AwaZam.dataZgloszenia, "d.m.yyyy") = '04.09.2015'
   AND (( Format(AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia, 'hh:mm') BETWEEN '00:00' AND '06:00' );
   ```
2. If you want, you can join both conditions together.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   dbAwarieZamkniete AS AwaZam
   WHERE (
       Format(AwaZam.dataZgloszenia, "d.m.yyyy") = '03.09.2015' 
       AND 
       (Format(AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia, 'hh:mm') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '23:59' )
         )

   or (
       Format(AwaZam.dataZgloszenia, "d.m.yyyy") = '04.09.2015' 
       AND 
       ( Format(AwaZam.godzinaZakonczenia, 'hh:mm') BETWEEN '00:00' AND '06:00' )
       )
   ```

Comment: Your query gives me empty results.

Comment: Try the first query again. Assuming rest of your query is correct except date format, It should work.

Comment: 2nd query gives me empty result again, 1st one contain syntax error somewhere.